# Eclipse Che docker image fails to start on Synology DS

Tags: docker, synology, eclipse-che

I have installed Dockers on my Synology DS. Then I downloaded the Eclipse Che image.
When I start the image, i keep seeing the following error in the logs.

```
!!! Docker socket (/var/run/docker.sock) hasn't be mounted inside the container. Verify the syntax of the "docker run" command.
```

The following are screenshots of the configuration of for the image. How do I get the container image going? Any help is fixing this problem will be much appreciated.

[image: General Settings]

[image: Volume]

[image: Port Settings]

[image: Links]

[image: Environment]

Answer (score 0):

What Che image are you trying to run?
Last version, which supported docker deployment was Che 6. Current version is 7.x, but since 7.x support of docker has been dropped and Che is supposed to run on k8s clusters.

But even if we are talking about Che6, Che server (the image you are probably trying to run) needs to have capability to connect to host docker daemon to spawn new containers (each workspace will be its own new container).
This is why, when starting che, you need to mount `/var/run/docker.sock`.

So the usual comand to start che in Che6 days was something like this:
`docker run -it --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v <path>:/data eclipse/che start`